# Are there restrictions on using UrlFetchApp with Triggers in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function that works fine when executing it manually, but not when I set up a trigger. UrlFetchApp doesn't return a response when the function is triggered.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation, but are there any scope restrictions (external_requests of UrlFetchApp) when using triggers that could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, exactly. It is not an error. This is the usual behavior of UrlFetchApp when your code runs by trigger. And, You can see an answer in detail given at this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3473).

Comment: As per ekoleda+devrel@google.com in your link: "These errors are typically related to missing robots.txt files or IP throttling/blocking at some level in your network stack. We won't be changing this architecture, but if there are specific URLs that you believe should be working and are failing mysteriously please open an individual bug to track them." I'm going to open a new issue to see what they say, but any idea if sites hosted on AWS should be creating this issue?

Comment: It works when I create a firewall rule to allow all ip addresses to my AWS server, instead of just the recommended Apps-Script server ip address ranges from the GAS docs.